# Get Procedure name inside ALTER_PROCEDURE DDL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I made a SQL trigger that sends email alerts whenever any stored procedure in my database is altered. Can I possibly include the name(s) of the SP's in the email? How can I call a specific SP name to appear in the email?

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [send_Email_to_User_ALTER]
ON DATABASE--msdb.dbo.[sp_send_dbmail]
AFTER ALTER_PROCEDURE
AS

--BEGIN 
--SET NOCOUNT ON;

EXEC msdb.dbo.[sp_send_dbmail]
@profile_name = 'Test Alert',
@recipients = 'email@outlook.com',
@body = 'A STORED PROCEDURE HAS BEEN ALTERED.'  , 
@subject = 'ALERT System SP Change Notification';
```

Comment: please correct the tags. your question's DBMS is MySQL or SQL Server? because you indicated the tsql too, which is for SQL Server!

Comment: Tsql can also be Sybase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [send_Email_to_User_ALTER] 
ON DATABASE--msdb.dbo.[sp_send_dbmail]
AFTER ALTER_PROCEDURE
AS


--BEGIN 
--SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()      
DECLARE @objName Nvarchar(max)
SET @objName = (SELECT  @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)'))

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @body = 'A STORED PROCEDURE HAS BEEN ALTERED.' + @objName 

EXEC msdb.dbo.[sp_send_dbmail]
@profile_name = 'Test Alert',
@recipients = 'email@outlook.com',
@body = @body , 
@subject = 'ALERT System SP Change Notification';
```

Comment: hi Vahid I am getting an error at the "+" sign next to "@objName" can you explain to me why this is?

Comment: The error I am getting states:                                                                    
 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
 Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: @SQLGuy I updated the answer. Now the error is resolved

Comment: @SQLGuy so you can touch the up vote and mark the post as Answer :-)